# How to boot into TWRP in Galaxy S5?

Tags: twrp

I was looking for the combination to go to recovery (TWRP) when the phone is currently off.

Comment: Did you take a look at [recovery-mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/recovery-mode/info)? :)

Answer (score 2):

The combination is Power + Volume UP + Home.